# Markdown doesn't work in attachments

Tags: slack-api

I'm creating a Slack integration with the Slack API. I followed [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting) but the markdown formatting doesn't work on my attachments...

Here is my response object:

```
{
  response_type: "in_channel",
  text: "List:",
  attachments: [
    { 
      text: "*pseudo*:\nbla bla bla",
      mrkdwn: true
    }
  ]
}
```

The "*" are displayed and not evaluated. Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Set the attribute `mrkdwn_in` in attachments:

```js
"attachments": [
    { 
      "text": "*pseudo*:\nbla bla bla",
      "mrkdwn_in": ["text"]
    }
]
```

See https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting for more information.

Comment: This did not work for me fully. E.g. the code is formatted correctly, but links are all wrong and bullets are not bullets. Pre-text is correctly formatted, but text incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

*Rep limit for commenting to an answer is stupid ... how are people supposed to get reputation if they cannot even interact with the forum.
Also sorry for necroing the old post, but it's the closest one to my issue that I've found so far.*

Anyways, the `mrkdwn_in` property doesn't help much with the stars `*` problem in the attachments.

```
"attachments": [
    {
      "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
      "color": "#000000",
      "mrkdwn_in": ["fields", "text"],
      "fields": [
        {
          "title": "XXXXXX",
          "value": "*PVC* avg: xxs, max: xxxs, avg-diff: xx% \n*EPH* avg: xxs, max: xxxs, avg-diff: xx%",
          "short": true
        },
        {
          "title": "XXXXXX",
          "value": "*PVC* avg: xxs, max: xxxs, avg-diff: xx% \n*EPH* avg: xxs, max: xxxs, avg-diff: xx%",
          "short": true
        }
      ]
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

After `avg-diff:` I'm inserting a string `" *↑* "` and concatenating it with the rest of the message.
For some reason the downwards arrow `" _↓_ "` gets translated to HTML correctly. It's just the `bold` that's broken.

As a result, the message still contains the `*` around the ASCII arrow, but the rest of the text like `*PVC*` gets translated into HTML correctly

[Screenshot of the attachment from Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIvJs.png)